# Linking C++ - BDB - LNK2001

Tags: linker, berkeley-db, lnk2001

BDB is compiled on the same PC, under same VS.

`#include <db_cxx.h>
int main(){
    Db b(NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}`

1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ""public: virtual __thiscall Db::~Db(void)" (??1Db@@UAE@XZ)"

1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ""public: __thiscall Db::Db(class DbEnv *,unsigned int)" (??0Db@@QAE@PAVDbEnv@@I@Z)"

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remember to link in the binary created by compiling BDB?

Comment: Now it tells me after start up "App. can't be started because libdb.lib wasn't found" (or something like that... I translate from Russian), but I've already added right link in linker->"Aditional dependences" [and -> "Resourse, linked with this"] ...

Comment: I've just made a copy of libdb.dll to programm root and it works)